# Domain forwarding causes a POST http request being interpreted as GET?

Tags: html, post, http-post, spring-rest

I have an html page which contains a form submission:

```
<form name="pc_request_form" action="https://coupon-liquibil.rhcloud.com/RequestPointCard" method="POST">
```

where https://coupon-liquibil.rhcloud.com is the url given by Openshift which hosts the application. This works well.

Now, I want to use my own "webcoupon.us" as the domain for the app, so I set a domain forwarding at the domain registrar (Google):

```
http://webcoupon.us **to** https://coupon-liquibil.rhcloud.com
```

At the same time, I changed the form header in my html file to:

```
<form name="pc_request_form" action="http://webcoupon.us/RequestPointCard" method="POST">
```

**My problem**: After this, whenever I submitted the form, I got an http error message:

```
Request method 'GET' not supported
```

At the same time, there is also this error message in my application log:

```
09:29:25,034 WARN [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] Request method 'GET' not supported
```

This error message (in my app log) led me to believe that

1. *http://webcoupon.us* in the http request (form submission) was correctly resolved to *https://coupon-liquibil.rhcloud.com* as intended. But
2. the request, after *http://webcoupon.us* being resolved, was interpreted by the server (my app) as a GET, rather than the intended POST request -- why is this?

The app was implemented in Springframework REST API. I also tried Godaddy for domain forwarding. The result was the same. **[END]**

Answer (score 1):

A POST to http://webcoupon.us/RequestPointCard returns an HTTP Redirect response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://app-coupondev.b9ad.pro-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com/RequestPointCard
```

This breaks the POST, 301 is only honored by GET/HEAD.  After this the user agent (may) issue a naked GET request instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I understand you correctly: domain forward 301 was intended for GET/HEAD requests, not for POST?

Comment: I searched online for "domain forward" descriptions, but could not find such statement as "Domain forward is for GET/HEAD requests only". 

Do I misunderstand?